# How do I stop VScode from creating the .vscode folder inside my source folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

VScode keeps creating this weird .vscode folder inside my source folder where my code is, it's super annoying and I want nothing to do with it. For some odd reason deleting it caused my program to bug out, of course I thought it was my code but I ctrl-z the entire code back where I started and it still did the same thing.
And I'm not using any build in compilers in vscode.

Comment: which file is inside the .vscode folder

Comment: When I start a new project I create a folder and click "Open Folder" in VSCode and I select that folder.

Comment: the `.vscode` folder typically contains some project settings (like settings for debugger, lauchers, ...)

Comment: Is it possible to disable it? Inside the folder is a "settings.json" and it has "files.associations"

Comment: you must have some extension that creates these files, see which setting is defined, `files.associations` is not a default VSC file, search the extension that creates these

Answer (score 3):

I've found the best thing to do here is setup a global .gitignore file and add `.vscode` to it https://sebastiandedeyne.com/setting-up-a-global-gitignore-file/

Comment: It doesn't solve OP's problem, though, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Some extensions might be creating this folder. Review the extensions you have installed and check their settings to see if any are set to generate a .vscode folder. Disable or reconfigure those extensions if needed.